# Is there a way to retrieve all the ancestor categories of page?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki-api

I'm exploring the MediaWiki API, and one of the things I want to accomplish is getting a page ancestor (not parent) category. 
Reading through some of the examples [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties), I tried getting [en:Albert Einstein's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) ancestor portal(s), for example, and wasn't successful.

Is it even possible?

Comment: not with a single query, no.

Comment: Are you asking about Portals or Categories? Those two are very different.

Answer (score 0):

For Wikipedia (and any Wikimedia project), you can use Magnus Manske's [reverse category tree](https://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/reverse_tree.php).

[Albert Einstein](https://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/reverse_tree.php?doit=1&language=en&project=wikipedia&title=Albert+Einstein&namespace=0) finds  10199 categories, allow me not to paste the output.